# PHP classes and error messaging

Tags: php, oop, error-handling

I am quite new to OOP and classes.  One thing I am struggling with is that if there are errors within a method of a class, no error messaging is displayed, the page just breaks.  Does anyone know why this is or how I can get this to display errors?

Comment: This has nothing to do with OOP or classes, but with error reporting. Take a look at [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php).

Comment: Fatal errors aren't specific to OOP.  `ini_set('display_errors', 1)`

Comment: -1 because you haven't shown that you've done any research on the topic. This is one of the most commonly asked questions regarding PHP so you should be able to find plenty of answers.

Comment: Are the downvotes due to the fact that he thought that the error messages were related to OOP? If so, I don't think they were deserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Put this at the top of the page that includes your class.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Comment: Id originally added this error reporting inside the class and not inside the page that includes the class.  I have moved it and it seems to be working.  Thanks.